# Flag restriction review

Tags: discussion, flag-ban

Some of my recent Flags were found to be invalid which resulted in me not being able to flag anymore. When I tried to review the flagged content again to know where I went wrong, I found that those posts are already deleted.

If the posts are deleted it indicates that there was some fact in my flagging, to my understanding these posts where answering for the sake of answering/asking their own question on existing question(I also face similar issue...).

I completely understand that different people can have different opinion on same issue, so I have nothing against my flag being rejected. I may also be at fault of not choosing correct category like choosing "spam" for a "low quality" answer but now I do not know to come out of this restriction? Is there a mechanism to come out of this restriction?

Could it be fair to expect, if flagged question was deleted, the flag rejection should not be counted against the flagger?

I am attaching screenshots for reference:
 [image]

Bottom line on my flag screen:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You used spam flags against [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783704/flume-and-hdfs-integration-hdfs-io-error/29098113#29098113) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411737/media-foundation-imfsinkwriterfinalize-method-fails-under-windows-7-when-mux/29098212#29098212). Those answers weren't really answers (they were follow-on questions), but they weren't spam.

Spam flags can carry heavy penalties, and can feed into audits and the anti-spam system in special ways, so we want to make sure people use them correctly. Therefore, we will decline spam flags on posts that aren't spam but still may need to have action taken on them.

You had also flagged two questions using custom moderator flags, instead of using standard close flags, and we had declined those for that reason. In addition to an answer of yours that you had flagged because it hadn't been accepted, which we also declined, these flags were enough to lead to a timed ban from flagging.

Hopefully, this should clear up why these flags were declined.

Comment: I agree that answer was either a followup question or an attempt to get a badge or points stealthily, which definitly do not demand 100 point penaly that comes with spam. To prevent nubes like me from wrongly marking spam if on first time marking spam popping a message with checkpoints to identify spam, may help a faster learning.

Comment: How long does the timed ban last? I'm in a similar situation.

Comment: @philshem - You should have been told that in the warning you received, but it looks like 2 days from what I can see on your account.